# Iphone Game, Full/Lite or in-app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am soon gonna release my first game on Apples AppStore, which is a Tower Defense game. My question is if the preferable choice is to release two version, one lite and one full, or to have one version with in-app purchase to unlock the rest of the game (levels 6-20)?

The first priority is to follow apple's guidelines (I do not want it rejected).
Second priority is financial (which gives the most money)
Lastly, which is easiest to maintain (I believe both methods are almost as easy to maintain if you do it right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that many developers faced this problem, and i believe, that in-app purchase give you lot's of benefits and is really a right way to go.

1. You don't split up downloads. All the purchases of your app counts to the only one.That puts you higher in the App Store. All the reviews. All the stars. That's what you want.
2. It's easier for user, who has chosen the free app to switch to the paid one. To press just one button is not the same as delete old one and install new app.
3. If saving user settings and progress is imortant for your app, you just save it in NSUserDefaults and continue using after upgrade. Imagine, what you'll need to do, if you have two separate apps.
4. Jailbreakers. They download cracked apps in Installous. Not your's.
5. You need to maintain only one app.

Of course, you'll need to implement in app purchase in your app, and there is still iAP cracker, but, as for me, choise is obvious.

Comment: Thanks. Sound reasonable. The advantage I have seen from Android Market is that having a full version really sorts of the bad reviews. I only get 4 or 5 starts on the full version. And it showed up in the Top New Paid Apps list which boosted the sales somewhat in the beginning. Do you know if piracy is a big problem? Or does people with jailbraked phone never pay for apps anyway? I am also considering having both in-app purchase and a full version.

Comment: I think, that when people with jailbraked phone see a crackedcapp, thry usually don't even think of buying it someday. But if they see, that app is really cool, and there is no way for thmcto get it for free-there's a chance, that they will upgrade oneday.